# How can I run two python script using the same pi camera in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, picamera

I am currently working on a project where I need to have a live stream video and a motion detection that when a motion is detected, the raspberry pi records a 10 second video. I have put each functionality in different python files. I am using a single Pi camera. I have also created a file that consists of all the camera functionality so that I don't need to initialize the picamera twice. In the live stream file there is a button that allows the user to activate the motion detection functionality. When the button is clicked an error is shown "Failed to enable connection: Out of Resources"(Note that the live stream is already running.). I just wanted to know if it is possible to run two programs simultaneously using a single pi camera. If it is possible, how? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now as Mark has already pointed it out. Someone asked sth similiar here as well: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=166384

Comment: You may wish to look at motion eye (https://github.com/motioneye-project/motioneye/tree/master/motioneye) for some ideas. It is a motion sensing/recording/streaming platform developed with python.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I will merge both files

Answer (score 0):

In general, AFAIK, it is not possible to access a single Raspberry Pi camera simultaneously from 2 separate processes.

I see a couple of possibilities which I'll describe in separate sections.

---

Use the shell and its [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command, to duplicate your video stream to 2 separate processes like this:

```
raspivid ... | tee >(MotionDetectionProcess) >(LiveStreamingProcess) > /dev/null
```

This is a `bash` *"process substitution"*.

You might use `raspividyuv` or `ffmpeg` or some other program, or even one written by yourself, to read the camera and pass the data to `stdout`.

This approach is very quick to set up and simple - everything just reads or writes its `stdin` or `stdout`. On the downside, everything must be started at the same time and things run in *"lock-step"* with each other.

---

Run a single video capture process, that simply writes the video frames into [multiprocessing shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

Write your other two programs separately, but such that they *"attach"* to the shared memory and get the frames from there rather than directly from the camera.

This approach is initially a bit harder to program, but things are more decoupled, so you may choose not to bother running motion detection one day, or to start it later or sooner, and your live stream will be unaffected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe the best solution is to merge both file together